# Python Twisted client not able to receive response from server

Tags: python, networking, twisted

I have a client written using python-twisted (http://pastebin.com/X7UYYLWJ) which sends a UDP packet to a UDP Server written in C using libuv. When the client sends a packet to the server, it is successfully received by the server and it sends a response back to the python client. But the client not receiving any response, what could be the reason ?

Comment: Don't reference external paste bins for your code.  Put the code in the SO question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately for you, there are many possibilities.

Your code uses `connect` to set up a "connected UDP" socket.  Connected UDP sockets filter the packets they receive.  If packets are received from any address other than the one to which the socket is connected, they are dropped.  It may be that the server sends its responses from a different address than you've connected to (perhaps it uses another port or perhaps it is multi-homed and uses a different IP).

Another possibility is that a NAT device is blocking the return packets.  UDP NAT hole punching has come a long way but it's still not perfect.  It could be that the server's response arrives at the NAT device and gets discarded or misrouted.

Related to this is the possibility that an intentionally configured firewall is blocking the return packets.

Another possibility is that the packets are simply lost.  UDP is not a reliable protocol.  A congested router, faulty networking gear, or various other esoteric (often transient) concerns might be resulting in the packet getting dropped at some point, instead of forwarded to the next hop.

Your first step in debugging this should be to make your application as permissive as possible.  Get rid of the use of connected UDP so that all packets that make it to your process get delivered to your application code.

If that doesn't help, use tcpdump or wireshark or a similar tool to determine if the packets make it to your computer at all.  If they do but your application isn't seeing them, look for a local firewall configuration that might reject them.

If they're not making it to your computer, see if they make it to your router.  Use whatever diagnostic tools are available (along the lines of tcpdump) on your router to see whether packets make it that far or not.  Or if there are no such tools, remove the router from the equation.  If you see packets making it to your router but no further, look for firewall or NAT configuration issues there.

If packets don't make it as far as your router, move to the next hop you have access to.  This is where things might get difficult since you may not have access to the next hop or the next hop might be the server (with many intervening hops - which you have to just hope are all working).

Does the server actually generate a reply?  What addressing information is on that reply?  Does it match the client's expectations?  Does it get dropped at the server's outgoing interface because of congestion or a firewall?

Hopefully you'll discover something interesting at one of these steps and be able to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. The problem was windows firewall. In firewall allowed programs settings, allowing the communication for pythonw/python did solve the problem. My python program was:

```
    from socket import *
    import time
    address = ( '192.168.1.104', 42) #Defind who you are talking to (must match arduino IP and port)
    client_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM) #Set Up the Socket
    client_socket.bind(('', 45)) # arduino sending to port 45
    client_socket.settimeout(1) #only wait 1 second for a response
    data = "xyz"
    client_socket.sendto(data, address)
    try:
            rec_data, addr = client_socket.recvfrom(2048) #Read response from arduino
            print rec_data #Print the response from Arduino
    except:
            pass
    while(1):
            pass
```

Comment: I wouldn't catch exceptions as widely as `except:` alone. Please narrow down exception type. thumbs up for providing standalone test code anyway.